# Delphi converting a C++ DLL string with BOM to string

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-xe2, byte-order-mark

I have a string coming from a C++ based DLL which can include a BOM and will be null terminated

I had originally been handling it by treating it as an array of char and casting the result as a PChar

```
function TRFCNWParameter.GetAsString: string;
const
  DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
var
  ResultSize: cardinal;
  Buffer: TArray<Char>;
  lErrorInfo: RRFCNWErrorInfo;
  RC: TRfcReturnCode;
begin
 SetLength(Buffer, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

 RC := RFCGetString(OwnerHandle, PChar(ParamName), @Buffer[0], Length(Buffer), ResultSize, @lErrorInfo);
 if (RC <> RFC_OK) and (ResultSize >= Length(Buffer)) then
 begin
   // resize buffer and retry
   SetLength(Buffer, ResultSize + 1);
   RC := RFCGetString(OwnerHandle, PChar(ParamName), @Buffer[0], Length(Buffer), ResultSize, @lErrorInfo);
 end;

 CheckForReturnedError(@lErrorInfo, 'Retrieve Parameter %s ' + ParamName);

 result := PChar(Buffer);
end;
```

Now I'm not overly familiar with how unicode strings appear in the debugger, but I notice when I evaluate the resultant string I can see the BOM

so a normal Delphi-sourced string would appear in single quotes:
`'test string'`
Strings from this routine may appear in the debugger as
`#FEFF'test string'`

it appears outside the single quotes which makes me doubt whether or not Delphi is intrinsically handling it.

As I'm getting issues parsing the output as XML however, I doubt it is. Therefore I am trying to do the conversion to native UTF-16

```
function TRFCNWParameter.GetAsString: string;
const
  DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
var
  ResultSize: cardinal;
  Buffer: TBytes;
  bufferCharLength: cardinal;
  lErrorInfo: RRFCNWErrorInfo;
  RC: TRfcReturnCode;
  char_size: cardinal;
begin
 char_size := 2;
 bufferCharLength := DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE;
 SetLength(Buffer, DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE * char_size);

 RC := RFCGetString(OwnerHandle, PChar(ParamName), @Buffer[0], bufferCharLength, ResultSize, @lErrorInfo);
 if (RC <> RFC_OK) and (ResultSize >= Length(Buffer)) then
 begin
   // resize buffer and retry
   bufferCharLength := (ResultSize + 1);
   SetLength(Buffer, bufferCharLength * CHAR_SIZE);
   RC := RFCGetString(OwnerHandle, PChar(ParamName), @Buffer[0], bufferCharLength, ResultSize, @lErrorInfo);
 end;

 CheckForReturnedError(@lErrorInfo, 'Retrieve Parameter %s ' + ParamName);
 result := TEncoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer); // needed to handle little-endian and BOM
end;
```

This, however, is not null-terminating the string leaving me with a load of 0s at the end. I guess I can cast to PChar and then cast back, `result := PChar(TEncoding.Unicode.GetString(buffer));` but that looks a bit ugly and makes me wonder whether I'm just doing this slightly wrong (or do I even need to do anything as the IDE is handling the BOM correctly)?

Comment: This API uses UTF-16 it would seem, so I don't see why you would bring UTF-8 into the mix. Just check the first to elements of the string. If they contain the UTF-16 BOM, remove them. The right way to allocate the return value is `SetString`. You already know the length. Don't go searching for a null terminator. That would also allow you to string the BOM by a bit of pointer manipulation when you call `SetString`. If you are going to try first with a fixed length buffer, allocate it on the stack. That way you can aim to get this done with just a single heap allocation.

Comment: Delphi is obviously not handling it. Delphi simply sees it as part of the text in the string. Since these seem to be WideChars, simply point your pointer past the first WideChar and you should be fine: `Result := PWideChar(@Buffer[1]);` This will automatically convert it to a string.

Comment: @Rudy Far better to use SetString to avoid scanning for the null when you already know where it is. If indeed the string that is returned is null terminated which we can't tell from here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the DLL communicates to an SAP server which can run on multiple architectures - there's definitely an ability for it to use big and little endian, I'm not so sure whether it runs on systems that natively use UTF-8. To be honest I'm not 100% clear whether the DLL always converts it to this flavour of unicode or whether it just pipes the result direct from the server. Unfortunately getting a server of the other endian-ness is non-trivial for a test case

Comment: @MattAllwood Clearly what the other end of the DLL call does is way beyond our expertise. But you need to know what it is doing. You certainly can't expect to interpret arbitrary encodings.

Comment: I just brought that up because I cannot always guarantee it to be UTF-16 LE unicode, but, seeing that I'm getting a BOM then it's reasonable to assume that if it is encoded in any other way then it should include a BOM which can be interpreted by the encoding routines. I'm just checking in the documentation whether it specifies UTF-16 output for this routine, but SAP aren't always great at their external docs.

Comment: That's not a reasonable assumption. For instance, the very fact that the DLL uses an array of 16 bit character elements rules out UTF-8.

Comment: @David: if the DLL sends a BOM, it should be possible to determine what the encoding is. Especially because 16-bit wide can be little or big endian. And it is not impossible to store 8-bit narrow text in a 16-bit buffer either. I would expect the DLL to take care of the differences. But you never know.

Comment: @David: Yes, probably SetString is better, if you trust ResultSize. If the string is not null terminated, then the assignment won't work anyway.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis The DLL works with `wchar_t` arrays, so no, it's not going to send anything other than utf-16. Why would you not trust `ResultSize`? I mean, coding is all about trusting the other side of an interface to do its job.

Comment: @David, Well, OP doesn't seem to trust them too much and docs are not very extensive. And of course you can store a `char` sequence in a `wchar_t` array, especially if you must handle both sizes.

Comment: @Remy The API works with `wchar_t` arrays........

Comment: If the DLL returns a BOM then the data can potentially be in multiple encodings. XML is a binary format with textual elements, it supports multiple encodings. You should read the DLL data as raw bytes, not as a Unicode string, and let your XML engine parse the raw bytes as needed, BOM and all. In fact, according to the [`RfcGetString()`](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nwpi711/7.1.1/en-US/48/b0e5af792d356be10000000a421937/content.htm) documentation, it actually takes a byte array for the output buffer, not a Unicode character array (`SAP_UC` is an `unsigned char` which is `Byte` in Delphi).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis You should not send byte oriented data in a `wchar_t` array.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `SAP_UC` is `wchar_t`. Given that this is XE2, and the second arg is passed as `PChar(ParamName)`, I think we can agree on that.

Comment: Yeah, my 2nd attempt after noticing the BOM is with the buffer as TBytes rather than TArray<char> as I had previously been assuming that I was going to get a sanitised Windows unicode string. I strongly suspect that I'm going to restricted to UTF-16 either BE or LE, so supporting these 2 is more important than anything too exotic. I'm erring towards `TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding` which takes in a TBytes and uses the BOM to get the correct TEncoding and then using the GetString routine, though this still seems to leave the #0.

Comment: It's going to be UTF16LE every single time. If you absolutely need to detect LE or BE don't waste your time with GetBufferEncoding. You just need to check a single Char against one of two values. The function works with WideChar. Because you call the Unicode version of the API. You seem to be over complicating things. Remy and Rudy aren't helping.

Comment: @MattAllwood when calling `TEncoding.GetString()`, it lets you pass in the buffer size to decode, so past in what `RfcGetString()` tells you in `ResultSize`. That will address the null terminator issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sure, if you KNOW the data is *always* UTF-16LE then you can avoid `TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding()` and skip the BOM manually. But, if you don't KNOW for sure `GetBufferEncoding()` can detect a BOM for you and return an index past the BOM, which can then be passed as input to `TEncoding.GetString()` along with the buffer size.

Comment: @Remy How many BOMs are there for 16 byte Unicode encodings?

Comment: @David: I don't send byte oriented data in a wchar_t array. But I could. <g> Anyway, I would not rule out that others do that too. Why does the text from the DLL come with a BOM, after all? Probably to indicate endianness, but who knows? FWIW; I would also only check the first two bytes and not use GetBufferEncoding. The latter is overkill, here.

Comment: OK thanks for the input guys. I think I'll try to write something assuming UTF-16LE with check for a BOM (and stripping if necessary) and have ask SAP (the DLL provider) to clarify whether other encodings will be used. Unfortunately the difficulty in procuring a BE test system precludes checking for ourselves, but fortunately that also means that we're going to get a bit of dead time before someone that uses it will run this code to get the answer and a patch if needed.

Comment: @MattAllwood handling UTF-16BE is very easy. If the BOM says the string is using UTF16-BE, simply make a copy of the string data ad then swap the bytes of each string character so they are in LE instead of BE. Do all of your processing in UTF-16LE only (since that is Delphi's native Unicode encoding), and then convert back to UTF16-BE only if needed (writing back to the DLL, etc).